# Getting exception while passing specific parameters in struts2 xml

Tags: java, xml, struts2, struts

Hi i am working on struts2, I am facing problem while passing specific parameters. My xml for controller is like below

```
<action name="summary/*/*" class="UserController" method="summary">
            <result>/view/user/Summary.jsp</result>
            <param name="type">{1}</param>
            <param name="user.loginName">{2}</param>
            <interceptor-ref name="caspianDefaultStack" />  
        </action>
```

If i pass url like `summary/profile/jhon` It work fine but when i pass url like `summary/profile/jhon.mickel` (If second parameter contains ".")  the method summary is not called why it is behaving in a strange way and how can i resolve this??

Comment: Actually nothing *strange* about that. Struts2 treats your last parameter like action with action suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to directly map the params in the wild-cards mapping. Something like this :

```
<action name="summary/{type}/{user.loginName}" class="UserController" method="summary">
            <result>/view/user/Summary.jsp</result>
            <interceptor-ref name="caspianDefaultStack" />  
        </action>
```

If that still doesn't work, then use `{FIELD_NAME:REGEX}` format. See the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) for example.